# php framework with plugins for spreadsheet generation, login/user system,twitter bootstrap integration?

Tags: codeigniter, cakephp, php

I am considering php framework Codeigniter & Cakephp for small site I would be developing but I am open to using pretty much any framework does fullfill the following requirements. requirements are:

- A simple pre-build user authentication system or login system as a plugin, something long
  the lines of [php-login-script](http://php-login-script.com/).
- Allows Easy integration with third-part excel/spreadsheet generation library or
  has some plugin.
- Should support `PHP 5.2`, hence symfony2 can't be considered
- Bonus points if the framework
  has integration with [twitter
  bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Looking for framework which can fullfill all of the above points, so I can save some time. Else, I would prefer framework which does *most* of the requirements & would write rest myself.

So, based on above requirements; which php framework/script would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP2

- User plugin https://github.com/cakedc/users
- Twitter Bootstrap https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap

There are plenty of different xls export helpers. Just google it and review them I can not recommend any of them because I have not used them. We have our own but we did not open source it.

Overall I would recommend to use CakePHP2 in any case over Codeigniter. I've recently had to convert a project from CI to Cake and now I know why... ;)

Comment: @burzum, Do you have any valid reasons for choosing CakePhp over CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know codeIgniter very well, but for Cakephp I can tell you that:

- Authentifiaction is easy to implement.
- It's easy to generate xml (which Excel can open), for .xls you'll have to do all by yourself.
- supports 5.2
- there is a [helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mxkocak/2011/11/16/twitter_bootstrap_style_for_cakephp_instantly) for twitter bootstrap, but I've never used it.

For me the deal breaker concerning CodeIgniter is the lack of built-in ORM. You should consider if you need one or not.

Comment: Thanks for response, I decided on CakePHP :)